# Official translation for "南繁"?

Tags: translation, names

Is there an official translation for "南繁"?

As in "南繁基地" and other "official" names.

I've looked on baidu and other sites but have only come up with things like "south reproduction"...

Edit:

Someone on 百度知道 defines it like this:
南繁，是我国作物育种的专有术语。意思是利用海南冬季大陆所不具备的光温条件对育种材料进行繁殖加代。比如大陆冬季（10-次年3月）水稻无法生长，在海南刚好完成一个生长季节。南繁不仅可以加快育种进程，而且可以利用不同的生态和土壤环境对杂交后代进行加压筛选，寻找到适用性广的材料，提高育种效果。

Comment: It's a place name, so the English translation is just the pinyin 'Nanfan'.

Comment: Yeah but it's used in a lot of company names...is the "official" translation really so boring?

Comment: I suppose so. Just like a lot of organizations have 上海 in their names and it's just Shanghai not anything like 'on the sea'...

Comment: Are you pronuncing something in NanHui dialect?

Comment: Well, if it is used in a company name, then only the company can give the "official" translation.

Comment: It sounds like a shortened form. 南繁基地 ~ 南部繁殖基地，南浦繁殖基地，南方繁殖基地

Comment: Not "official" enough, but the official English name for "三亚市南繁科学技术研究院" is "Sanya Science & Technology Academy for **Crop Winter Multiplication**", whose words in bold are the corresponding part for "南繁".

Comment: @Stan thanks for your research - it helped me start looking in the right direction -- check out my answer and see what you think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I am mistaken but I think the offical translation for `南繁` is:

> Hainan National Breeding and Multiplication (HNBM)

From [中国农学通报 Chinese Agricultural Science Bulletin (2013,29(27):135-140)](http://www.casb.org.cn/CN/article/downloadArticleFile.do?attachType=PDF&id=29372):

> ## 国家南繁育制种基地正规化建设的关键问题分析
>
> 陈冠铭1,2，李劲松1,3，林亚琼1，汪李平2
>   （1三亚市南繁科学技术研究院，海南三亚572000；2华中农业大学园艺林学学院，武汉430070；
>   3海南省南繁管理办公室，海南三亚572000）
>
> ## 摘要：
>
> 通过对南繁科技性与历史性、海南南繁不可替代性、南繁功能价值层次结构以及存在的关键问题
>   进行分析，得出南繁已上升为国家战略，成为国家战略性资源。海南南繁作为科研实践与历史的选择的
>   重大成果，在气候条件、科学育种、粮食生产抗灾救灾、保障种业安全和区位优势等方面发挥着不可替代
>   的作用；同时通过引入价值工程、产业集群、区域经济等理念，在研究南繁的功能、价值和存在的关键问
>   题基础上，建立南繁功能价值的层次结构。但要实现南繁产业集群化发展，充分实现南繁功能价值，必
>   须要解决南繁在顶层规划、试验用地、制度设计、硬件建设和生态安全等方面存在的关键问题。提出了
>   建设南繁育种科研核心保护区、完善南繁法规政策保障机制、健全南繁管理体制、编制实施南繁育制种 基地发展规划、争取国家政策资金支持等建议。
>
> ## 关键词：
>
> 南繁；价值工程；基础功能；科技功能；社会价值；南繁定位 中图分类号：S-3 文献标志码：A 论文编号：2012-3921

+

> ## Analysis on the Key Issues About the Regularized Construction of the Base of Hainan National Breeding and Multiplication
>
> Li Jinsong1,3, Lin Yaqiong1, Wang Liping2 (1Sanya Sci-tech Academy of
>   Hainan National Breeding and Multiplication, Sanya Hainan 572000;
>   2College of Horticulture and Forestry, Huazhong Agricultural
>   University, Wuhan 430070; 3Hainan Province Management Office of Hainan
>   National Breeding and Multiplication, Sanya Hainan 572000)
>
> ## Abstract:
>
> By analyzing technology features, historical characteristics,
>   irreplaceability, function and value hierarchy, and the key problems
>   of Hainan National Breeding and Multiplication (HNBM in short, its
>   essence is the off-season breeding and seed production, its base is
>   similar to winter nursery and shuttle breeding), showed that HNBM had
>   risen as a national strategy and became a national strategic resource.
>   HNBM as the major achievement of the practice of scientific research
>   and the choice of history, played an irreplaceable role in the
>   climatic conditions, scientific breeding, grain production in disaster
>   relief, protecting the safety of the seed industry and locational
>   advantages. At the same time, through introducing concepts of value
>   engineering, industrial clusters and regional economy, on the basis of
>   the research of the function and the value and the key problems, we
>   established the function and value hierarchy of HNBM. But to fully
>   achieve the development of industrial clusters and the functional
>   value of the HNBM, we might solve the key issues of the HNBM in the
>   top-level planning, experimental bases, system design, hardware
>   construction and ecological security. This paper presented some
>   suggestion to build the research core protected areas of HNBM, improve
>   the regulations and policies safeguard mechanism and management system
>   of HNBM, draw up and carry out the base development planning of HNBM,
>   and seek government support.
>
> ## Key words:
>
> Hainan National Breeding and
>   Multiplication (HNBM); value engineering; basic functions; technology
>   functions; social value; location of HNBMChen Guanming1,2,

each instance of `南繁` is translated as either `Hainan National Breeding and Multiplication` or `HNBM`

Comment: As a Chinese who has also written several research papers, I can tell that the English translation in Chinese journals cannot always be trusted.

Comment: @fefe you're right, *not always*. According to [this post](http://emuch.net/html/201003/1856752.html), that journal isn't a very good one, so I'm afraid the peer-review process might not be rigorous enough.

Comment: @Stan The English on good journals are also kind of poor. I also contributed some poor English :( When things come to this kind of translation of names, people tend to "invent" a translation themselves if they cannot find a well accepted one. So sometimes, several translations may be invented by different authors for the same term. It is hard to say which would be well accepted until after several years. Also, whether the well accepted translation sounds right to a native English speaker remains questionable.

Comment: It definitely depends on which aspect of the meaning of the word (the technology? the organisation?) you are trying to convey, and to whom (general public? experts aware of the technology?). Translation, be it official or not, without context is kind of undiscussable.